# jquery autocomplete suggest item can't select using keyboard arrow key

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

this code work perfectly but i can't able to select a item from the suggest list using keyboard up and down key only can select using mouse what's the problem?

please help someone :/ :/ :/

https://jsfiddle.net/g60wc776/

```js
/********************************************************************************
/*
 * triggeredAutocomplete (jQuery UI autocomplete widget)
 * 2012 by Hawkee.com (hawkee@gmail.com)
 *
 * Version 1.4.5
 * 
 * Requires jQuery 1.7 and jQuery UI 1.8
 *
 * Dual licensed under MIT or GPLv2 licenses
 *   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License
 *   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License
 *
*/

;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {
    $.widget("ui.triggeredAutocomplete", $.extend(true, {}, $.ui.autocomplete.prototype, {
        
        options: {
            trigger: "@",
            allowDuplicates: true
        },

        _create:function() {

            var self = this;
            this.id_map = new Object();
            this.stopIndex = -1;
            this.stopLength = -1;
            this.contents = '';
            this.cursorPos = 0;
            
            /** Fixes some events improperly handled by ui.autocomplete */
            this.element.bind('keydown.autocomplete.fix', function (e) {
                switch (e.keyCode) {
                    case $.ui.keyCode.ESCAPE:
                        self.close(e);
                        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                        break;
                    case $.ui.keyCode.UP:
                    case $.ui.keyCode.DOWN:
                        if (!self.menu.element.is(":visible")) {
                            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                        }
                }
            });

            // Check for the id_map as an attribute.  This is for editing.

            var id_map_string = this.element.attr('id_map');
            if(id_map_string) this.id_map = jQuery.parseJSON(id_map_string);

            this.ac = $.ui.autocomplete.prototype;
            this.ac._create.apply(this, arguments);

            this.updateHidden();

            // Select function defined via options.
            this.options.select = function(event, ui) {
                var contents = self.contents;
                var cursorPos = self.cursorPos;

                // Save everything following the cursor (in case they went back to add a mention)
                // Separate everything before the cursor
                // Remove the trigger and search
                // Rebuild: start + result + end

                var end = contents.substring(cursorPos, contents.length);
                var start = contents.substring(0, cursorPos);
                start = start.substring(0, start.lastIndexOf(self.options.trigger));

                var top = self.element.scrollTop();
                this.value = start + self.options.trigger+ui.item.label+' ' + end;
                self.element.scrollTop(top);

                // Create an id map so we can create a hidden version of this string with id's instead of labels.

                self.id_map[ui.item.label] = ui.item.value;
                self.updateHidden();

                /** Places the caret right after the inserted item. */
                var index = start.length + self.options.trigger.length + ui.item.label.length + 2;
                if (this.createTextRange) {
                    var range = this.createTextRange();
                    range.move('character', index);
                    range.select();
                } else if (this.setSelectionRange) {
                    this.setSelectionRange(index, index);
                }
                
                return false;
            };

            // Don't change the input as you browse the results.
            this.options.focus = function(event, ui) { return false; }
            this.menu.options.blur = function(event, ui) { return false; }

            // Any changes made need to update the hidden field.
            this.element.focus(function() { self.updateHidden(); });
            this.element.change(function() { self.updateHidden(); });
        },

        // If there is an 'img' then show it beside the label.

        _renderItem:  function( ul, item ) {
            if(item.img != undefined) {
                return $( "<li></li>" )
                    .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                    .append( "<a>" + "<img src='" + item.img + "' /><span>"+item.label+"</span></a>" )
                    .appendTo( ul );
            }        
            else {    
                return $( "<li></li>" )
                    .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                    .append( $( "<a></a>" ).text( item.label ) )
                    .appendTo( ul );
            }
        },

        // This stops the input box from being cleared when traversing the menu.

        _move: function( direction, event ) {
            if ( !this.menu.element.is(":visible") ) {
                this.search( null, event );
                return;
            }
            if ( this.menu.first() && /^previous/.test(direction) ||
                    this.menu.last() && /^next/.test(direction) ) {
                this.menu.deactivate();
                return;
            }
            this.menu[ direction ]( event );
        },

        search: function(value, event) {

            var contents = this.element.val();
            var cursorPos = this.getCursor();
            this.contents = contents;
            this.cursorPos = cursorPos;

            // Include the character before the trigger and check that the trigger is not in the middle of a word
            // This avoids trying to match in the middle of email addresses when '@' is used as the trigger

            var check_contents = contents.substring(contents.lastIndexOf(this.options.trigger) - 1, cursorPos);
            var regex = new RegExp('\\B\\'+this.options.trigger+'([\\w\\-]+)');

            if (contents.indexOf(this.options.trigger) >= 0 && check_contents.match(regex)) {

                // Get the characters following the trigger and before the cursor position.
                // Get the contents up to the cursortPos first then get the lastIndexOf the trigger to find the search term.

                contents = contents.substring(0, cursorPos);
                var term = contents.substring(contents.lastIndexOf(this.options.trigger) + 1, contents.length);

                // Only query the server if we have a term and we haven't received a null response.
                // First check the current query to see if it already returned a null response.

                if(this.stopIndex == contents.lastIndexOf(this.options.trigger) && term.length > this.stopLength) { term = ''; }
            
                if(term.length > 0) {
                    // Updates the hidden field to check if a name was removed so that we can put them back in the list.
                    this.updateHidden();
                    return this._search(term);
                }
                else this.close();
            }    
        },

        // Slightly altered the default ajax call to stop querying after the search produced no results.
        // This is to prevent unnecessary querying.

        _initSource: function() {
            var self = this, array, url;
            if ( $.isArray(this.options.source) ) {
                array = this.options.source;
                this.source = function( request, response ) {
                    response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(array, request.term) );
                };
            } else if ( typeof this.options.source === "string" ) {
                url = this.options.source;
                this.source = function( request, response ) {
                    if ( self.xhr ) {
                        self.xhr.abort();
                    }
                    self.xhr = $.ajax({
                        url: url,
                        data: request,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(data) {
                            if(data != null) {
                                response($.map(data, function(item) {
                                    if (typeof item === "string") {
                                        label = item;
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        label = item.label;
                                    }
                                    // If the item has already been selected don't re-include it.
                                    if(!self.id_map[label] || self.options.allowDuplicates) {
                                        return item
                                    }
                                }));
                                self.stopLength = -1;
                                self.stopIndex = -1;
                            }
                            else {
                                // No results, record length of string and stop querying unless the length decreases
                                self.stopLength = request.term.length;
                                self.stopIndex = self.contents.lastIndexOf(self.options.trigger);
                                self.close();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                };
            } else {
                this.source = this.options.source;
            }
        },

        destroy: function() {
            $.Widget.prototype.destroy.call(this);
        },

        // Gets the position of the cursor in the input box.

        getCursor: function() {
            var i = this.element[0];

            if(i.selectionStart) {
                return i.selectionStart;
            }
            else if(i.ownerDocument.selection) {
                var range = i.ownerDocument.selection.createRange();
                if(!range) return 0;
                var textrange = i.createTextRange();
                var textrange2 = textrange.duplicate();

                textrange.moveToBookmark(range.getBookmark());
                textrange2.setEndPoint('EndToStart', textrange);
                return textrange2.text.length;
            }
        },

        // Populates the hidden field with the contents of the entry box but with 
        // ID's instead of usernames.  Better for storage.

        updateHidden: function() {
            var trigger = this.options.trigger;
            var top = this.element.scrollTop();
            var contents = this.element.val();
            for(var key in this.id_map) {
                var find = trigger+key;
                find = find.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9@]+/g,'\\$&');
                var regex = new RegExp(find, "g");
                var old_contents = contents;
                contents = contents.replace(regex, trigger+'['+this.id_map[key]+']');
                if(old_contents == contents) delete this.id_map[key];
            }
            $(this.options.hidden).val(contents);
            this.element.scrollTop(top);
        }

    }));  
                })( jQuery, window , document );
                
                $('#inputbox').triggeredAutocomplete({
   hidden: '#hidden_inputbox',
    source: [
 "Asp",
 "BASIC",
 "COBOL",
 "ColdFusion",
 "Erlang",
 "Fortran",
 "Groovy",
 "Java",
 "JavaScript",
 "Lisp",
 "Perl",
 "PHP",
 "Python",
 "Ruby",
 "Scala",
 "Scheme"
 ],
   trigger: "@" 
});
```

```html
<textarea id='inputbox' style='width: 400px; height: 90px;'></textarea>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: this plugin requires jQuery 1.7 and jQuery UI 1.8. [updated fiddel](https://jsfiddle.net/g60wc776/1/)

Comment: thaks for ur answer. how can i colored the match text
_renderItem:  function( ul, item ) {
             
                return $( "<li></li>" )
                    .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                    .append( $( "<a></a>" ).text( item.label ) )
                    .appendTo( ul );
            }
        },

Comment: it's enough to overwrite part of the class:  .ui-corner-all {  color: red !important;  }

Comment: i want to color the matched text on the append list. how can i do in the renderitem function